# Push into array inside object failing (JavaScript inside WebBrowser control)

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a `WebBrowser` control in my C# application which loads a page that has JavaScript on it. I am trying to push elements inside an array that's inside an object:

```
var myObj = { "foo": [] };
```

For example, if the user clicks a button on the page, I will do this:

```
myObj.foo.push(element);
```

This works perfectly fine if I test it inside an actual browser such as IE, Firefox, or Chrome. But when I run it through my application, it doesn't push anything. I added alerts before and after the `push` line and it only shows the `alert` before the `push` line (Shows both if I test on the browsers mentioned above). I don't know how to debug it as I can't add breakpoints to the JavaScript code in Visual Studio.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: To help debug, I suppose you could pop some alerts up with the values of `myObj` and `myObj.foo`.

Comment: I tried that as well. If I do `alert(myObj)`, it prints out `Object object`. If I try to alert the values of `myObj.foo`, nothing pops up. Of course, works fine in the other browsers.

Comment: I tried running those two lines in a WebBrowser control and it worked for me.  Can you share more code?

Comment: So I figured it out. I had to do `myObj['foo'].push(element)` instead. Makes no sense, but it's working now. Maybe my `WebBrowser` version is different than yours.

Comment: Well, glad your problem is solved.